# When does the controller get loaded in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have a controller and a view for that controller. In the view, I render a lot of UI components like dropdowns, text fields etc.

There is a `date_select` in the UI which lists all the months and years from a certain table. By default, `date_select` selects the current month and current year in it.

There is a label just below the `date_select` which is supposed to show the number of business days in the month & year selected in the `date_select`.

I have written a JavaScript event handler (which calls a controller function as well) which is invoked when the user changes the value selected in the `date_select`). And the event handler calculates the number of business days (inside the controller function based on the working days present in another table) and displays it in the label below the `date_select`.

This event handler workds perfectly fine. But when the UI is loaded for the very first time, the label does not get populated at all. Looks like my controller is not getting invoked at all!

When the UI is rendered for the first time, won't the controller be invoked at all? If it does, will Rails be invoking the `init` method inside the controller first?

Comment: Posting some js and html code you've written would help others to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the controller action for calculating the business days won't be invoked. You need to send the ajax request to controller for calculating Business days on page load with current month and year params.

Comment: Won't the controller be initialized either when UI is rendered? What event should I handle in my javascript when the page is rendered (so that I can call my controller explicitly to calculate business days based on the `date_select` default selection)?

Comment: @Biju What about trying `onLoad`, `onChange` etc.?

Comment: @sawa - I used the `ready` event and it worked for me. Thanks all for your help!